# Is there NULL/NIL value in numpy? for np.uint16 ! beside -1?

Tags: python, numpy, null

I'm using np.isin() to calculate overlap between two values ... f.e.

```
np.isin(randint(0,10,3), randint(0,10,3)).sum()
```

the problem is I have a case where I need **NULL value** (all zero rows  would be good candidate) :

```
  z = np.array([0, 0, 0], dtype=np.uint16)
  np.isin(z,array([0,2,3])).sum()
  : 3
```

but the overlap should be ZERO not 3, because ZERO is real data. 
Currently I use null-value of 65535 i.e. -1, which I dont like very much :

```
  z = np.array([0, 0, 0], dtype=np.uint16) + np.uint16(-1)
  np.isin(z, np.array([0,2,3], dtype=np.uint16)).sum()
  : 0
```

The problem as you see is that the NULL value can not be ZERO, because ZERO is value that is legitimate data..

Is there some standardized way of handling NIL/NULL data in numpy ?

---

I also should have mentioned the type should be np.uint16

```
In [137]: zz = np.zeros(5, dtype=np.uint16)

In [138]: zz
Out[138]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint16)

In [139]: zz[:] = np.nan

In [140]: zz
Out[140]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint16)
```

Comment: There is np.nan

Comment: `np.nan` is available for float arrays.  But equality and `in` tests are unreliable with floats.  Python `None` only works in `object` dtype arrays.  Both `None` and `np.nan` require special equality handling (e.g.  `x is None` instead of `x==None`).  For nonnegative ints, `-1` might work as `null`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.nan`:

```
>>> np.nan == np.nan
False
>>> z = np.array([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan])
>>> np.isin(z,np.array([np.nan,2,3])).sum()
0
```